# App doesn't complete the api call through firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

***Edited: added frontend code. Removed routes that are not being tested.

***Edited2: added all code for frontend and backend

***Edited3: modified the details of error because it doesn't have to do with e.preventDefault().

I'm fairly new to google firebase functions.

For some reason when my frontend makes an api call to the backend, the app doesn't seem to complete the api call. Im not sure why. The endpoints are correct. I get a console message from the backend. Here is my code for reference

frontend:

```
const form = document.querySelector('.donate-form');
const input = document.querySelector('.search');
const submitBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.submit-button');
const orgContainer = document.querySelector('.org-container');
const searchForm = document.querySelector('.search-form');
const search = document.querySelector('.search');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.previous-button');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-button');
let buttonId ='';
let query = '';
let pgCounter = 0;
const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/pledge-test-aa5d1/us-central1/api'

function renderResults(results){
    console.log("The results>>>",results);
    results.forEach(item =>{
        if(item.name && item.website_url && item.logo_url){
            const orgCard = document.createElement('div');
            orgCard.classList.add('org-card')
            orgCard.innerHTML = `
            <h1 class="org-name">${item.name}</h1>
            <div class ="logo-container">
                <a href = ${item.website_url} target="_blank"><img class = "org-logo" src = "${item.logo_url}" alt = logo width="250" height="250" /></a>
            </div>
            `;
            orgContainer.appendChild(orgCard)
        }
        else{
            const orgCard = document.createElement('div');
            orgCard.classList.add('org-card')
            orgCard.innerHTML = `
            <h1 class="org-name">${item.name}</h1>
            <div class ="logo-container">
               <p>logo unavailable</p>
            </div>
            `;
            orgContainer.appendChild(orgCard)
        }
       
    })
}

function fetchInfo(endpoint){
    console.log("Hey Baus");
    return fetch(endpoint,{
       method:'GET'
   },
   ).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
       return response.json();
   }).then((jsonResponse)=>{
    //use .childElementCount to check if a parent container has child elements
        if(orgContainer.childElementCount > 0){
            orgContainer.innerHTML = '';
        }
       try{
           console.log(jsonResponse);
           renderResults(jsonResponse.results);
       }catch(error){
           console.log("there is an error>>>",error);
       }
   });
}

function handleClick(e){
    const idNum = e.target.id;
    query =''
    pgCounter = 1;
    // if (buttonId == idNum){
    //     console.log("same id. exiting");
    //     return;
    // }
        buttonId = idNum;
        console.log("the id of button is >>>",buttonId);
        const endpoint = `${baseURL}/organizations?cause_id=${idNum}`;
        fetchInfo(endpoint);
}

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log('hey baus. final query is>>>',query);
    const queryEndpoint = `${baseURL}/searchOrg?q=${query}`;
    fetchInfo(queryEndpoint)
    setTimeout(()=>{
        search.value = '';

    },3000)
}

const handleChange=(e) =>{
    query = e.target.value;
    buttonId = '';
    pgCounter = 1;
    //console.log("The searched term is>>>", query);
    const queryEndpointInt = `${baseURL}/searchOrg?q=${query}`;
    fetchInfo(queryEndpointInt)
}
const handleNext = (e) =>{
    pgCounter++;
    console.log("the counter is now>>>", pgCounter);
    if(!query && !buttonId){
        const endpoint = `${baseURL}/next?page=${pgCounter}`;
        fetchInfo(endpoint);
    }
    if(query){
        //buttonId='';
        const endpoint = `${baseURL}/next?page=${pgCounter}&q=${query}`;
        fetchInfo(endpoint);
    }
    if(buttonId){
        //query ='';
        console.log("There is a buttonId>>",buttonId);
        const endpoint = `${baseURL}/next?page=${pgCounter}&cause_id=${buttonId}`; 
        fetchInfo(endpoint);
    }

}
const handlePrev = (e) => {
    //console.log(e);
    if(pgCounter ==1){
        console.log("number is one");
        pgCounter=1;
        return;
    }
    else{
        pgCounter--;
        console.log("the counter is now>>>", pgCounter);
    }
    
    if(!query && !buttonId){
        const endpoint = `${baseURL}/next?page=${pgCounter}`;
        fetchInfo(endpoint);
    }
    // if(!query && buttonId){
    //     const endpoint = `http://localhost:4001/next?page=${pgCounter}&cause_id=${buttonId}`;
    //     fetchInfo(endpoint);
    // }

    if(query){
        //buttonId='';
        const endpoint = `${baseURL}/next?page=${pgCounter}&q=${query}`;
        fetchInfo(endpoint);
    }
    if(buttonId){
        //query='';
        const endpoint = `${baseURL}/next?page=${pgCounter}&cause_id=${buttonId}`; 
        fetchInfo(endpoint);
    }

}

submitBtn.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', handleClick));
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', handlePrev);
nextBtn.addEventListener('click',handleNext);
searchForm.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
search.addEventListener('input',handleChange);
```

backend:

```
// my code
const express = require("express");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
require("dotenv").config();
// const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4001;
// **this will cause an error with cloud functions
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require("axios");
const baseURL = "https://api.pledge.to/v1/organizations";
const myHeader = {
  "Authorization": `Bearer ${process.env.API_KEY}`,
};

// Instantiate the app here
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

// Use static server to serve the Express Yourself Website
// app.use(express.static('public'));

// app.listen(PORT, () => {
//   console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
// });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Hello World");
  res.status(200).send("baus");
});

app.get("/organizations", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Making API call");
  console.log(req.query.cause_id);
  try {
    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
    const response = await axios.get(baseURL+"?"+`cause_id=${req.query.cause_id}`, {
      headers: myHeader,
    });
    const data = await response.data;
    res.status(200).send(data);
    // res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({error: "Internal Server Error"});
  }
});

app.get("/searchOrg", async (req, res)=> {
  console.log("Search query >>>", req.query.q);
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(baseURL+"?"+`q=${req.query.q}`, {
      headers: myHeader,
    });
    const data = await response.data;
    res.status(200).send(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({error: "Internal Server Error"});
  }
});

app.get("/next", async (req, res)=>{
  // console.log("Im in the next endpoint");
  // Using template literals
  let queryString = " ";
  // eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in
  for (const key in req.query) {
    queryString += `${key}=${req.query[key]}&`;
  }
  // Remove the trailing '&' if necessary
  queryString = queryString.slice(0, -1);

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(baseURL+"?"+`${queryString}`, {
      headers: myHeader,
    });
    const data = await response.data;
    res.status(200).send(data);
    // res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({error: "Internal Server Error"});
  }
});

// Listen command
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I tested it using `firebase emulators:start`. I made sure to update the endpoints on my frontend so that it sends the request to the right server.

I checked the network tab when I make the api call and it says I am getting a `101 status code` and a type `websocket` Also for some reason the amount of time it is taking to process the request is `pending`

It seems like the websocket is "switching protocols". This is based on my research. Maybe this is causing the unexpected behavior.

Any ideas why this could be happening? Could it be that I configured the hosting wrong for my frontend. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. Happy coding!

Comment: Since the error is being reported by your client code, you should probably show that as well.  We should be able to reproduce the issue using the code you provide.  I'll point out that you show 4 routes here, but we don't know which one is being invoked.

Comment: If I had to guess, you've got an un-cancelled navigation event like an anchor click or form submit (ie missing `e.preventDefault()`). Can't tell without seeing that code though

Comment: As expected, your `handleClick()` function is missing `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Hi Phil thanks for your response! I tried including the ```e.preventDefault```. In the handleClick function. however i still get the same problem. It might have something to do with the websocket switching protocols? Although im not sure. Thanks for your help! Happy coding :)